# Windows Software Updater that searches for all software on PC

Tags: windows, software

For the last few years, I've used SUMo to keep software on Windows 10 PC's updated. With its passing, I'm looking for a replacement that meets my needs. Though I've searched the web, most tools I've tried, such as those at [AlternativeTo.net](https://alternativeto.net/software/sumo/), only check the Windows Registry for applications using MSI installers, ignoring portable applications such as HWinfo and many from Nirsoft and O&O software, and some do not have inclusive databases, ignoring even some MSI installed apps.

The tool I'd like has a few qualifications:

- It can **search thoroughly for all applications**, including those manually copied to *Program Files*, *Program Files (x86)*, and a few oddballs that must be placed in other folders.
- It has an **inclusive database of applications** (likely online) and their current versions.
- It is **free**, or freemium.
- It **is not required that it be able to install updates**, whether manually or automatically, since I prefer to read the changelog/version history and check files at VirusaTotal before using them.

BTW, SUMo can *still* catalog all software, and produce a useful report, however it can no longer contact an online database of app versions.

*Addendum:* Though I've found [UCheck](https://www.adlice.com/ucheck/) from Adlice Software performs a more thorough scan for all software, I'd still like to know of other tools that might be better, or free, rather than freemium.